Login with external IdP inside a Java Application and do a succesful SSO
i need to integrate SAML authentication with an external IdP for SSO in a Java application.
I can authenticate in two ways: or with X509 certificate or with username and password.
How can i do that in Java?
I saw OpenSAML, but i have a lot of concerns about feasibility. I'm not expert about SAML.
All that i have is the IdP metadata.
